# irb doesn't load gem that I created

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby, irb

I'm using `jruby` in `1.9` mode.

```
➜  nittresults git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
jruby 1.6.7.2 (ruby-1.9.2-p312) (2012-05-01 26e08ba) (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_24) [darwin-x86_64-java]
➜  nittresults git:(master) ✗ which gem
gem: aliased to jruby --1.9 -S gem
➜  nittresults git:(master) ✗ which irb
irb: aliased to jruby --1.9 -S irb
```

I have created a gem nittresults, after installing it I can't load it inside irb. The error message is shown below

```
➜  nittresults git:(master) ✗ gem list | grep -i nitt
nittresults (0.0.1)
➜  nittresults git:(master) ✗ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'nittresults'
LoadError: no such file to load -- nittresults
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1042:in `require'
    from /Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1088:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1410:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1197:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1197:in `catch'
    from /Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin/jirb:13:in `(root)'
```

How can I get it to load inside of irb?
I'm on osx snow leopard 10.6.8.

Here is the output og `gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2012-05-01 patchlevel 312) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Gems/1.9
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin/jruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.6
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Gems/1.9
     - /Users/User/.gem/jruby/1.9
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Here's the output of `puts $:`

```
➜  nittresults git:(master) ✗ irb      
irb(main):001:0> puts $:
/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9
/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared
/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8
/Library/Frameworks/JRuby.framework/Versions/Current/lib/ruby/1.9
=> nil
```

Comment: Why is your 1.9 ruby loading rubygems from 1.8? Look at your error, the path leads to v1.8 rubygems...that's not right.

Comment: What information can I check to fix this?

Comment: Add `gem env` output to your question. Also do you do you have a `GEM_HOME` or `GEM_PATH` environmental variable defined (`echo $GEM_HOME $GEM_PATH` )?

Comment: I have added the output of `gem env` and GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH aren't set.

Comment: @Casper, I've posted those. Any suggestions as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: Well..no :-/ What does `RUBY_VERSION` and `$LOAD_PATH` show in your `irb`? Do you have a previous ruby 1.8 installation on that machine? What's in your `~/.irbrc`, anything affecting the load path in there? Also does your gem contain a file `lib/nittresults.rb`?

Comment: RUBY_VERSION isn't set neither is LOAD_PATH. I don't have `.irbrc` in my home directory and the gem does contains that file. As a side note, I used bundler to create the initial structure but changed the module name form `Nittresults` to `NittResults` but I also reflected this in the gemrc and the gem builds and installs fine.

Comment: In irb type `puts $:`. What's in there?

Comment: That output is strange, added it in the question

Comment: @Casper : did that too, what now?

Comment: A reinstall of jruby with rbenv seems to have fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate rubygems first:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'nittresults'
require 'nittresults'
```

Comment: He's using 1.9, which doesn't need `require 'rubygems'` (though perhaps it's different in JRuby?).

Comment: There's something fishy with his installation. Check out the error, it's from libs in ruby 1.8..

Comment: The installation was indeed corrupted in this case, A clean install with rbenv fixed this. @Casper could you add this as an answer?